# Facebook setting for Invite friend in Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It may be an easy question but can anybody tell me.

Is there any setting we need to do in the app (in Facebook developer site) for invite friends?

I have done all in code to invite friends.

When I substitute the Facebook APP ID of a sample code in which invite friend is working, then my code is also working fine.

But when I substitute my APP ID then the process is going fine, showing me successfully invitation message, but invitation is not sent.

I am using the following code:

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                              message:FacebookInviteMessage
                                                title:@"Invite Friends"
                                           parameters:parameters
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {

                                                  NSString *strResultUrl = [resultURL absoluteString];

                                                  if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogCompleted && ![strResultUrl isEqualToString:@"fbconnect://success"])
                                                  {
                                                      MIDLog(@"Web dialog complete: %@", resultURL);

                                                      if (![resultURL query])
                                                      {
                                                          return;
                                                      }

                                                      NSDictionary *params = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                                                      NSMutableArray *recipientIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                                      for (NSString *paramKey in params)
                                                      {
                                                          if ([paramKey hasPrefix:@"to["])
                                                          {
                                                              [recipientIDs addObject:[params objectForKey:paramKey]];
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                      if ([params objectForKey:@"request"])
                                                      {
                                                          NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", [params objectForKey:@"request"]);
                                                      }
                                                      if ([recipientIDs count] > 0)
                                                      {
                                                          //[self showMessage:@"Sent request successfully."];
                                                          //NSLog(@"Recipient ID(s): %@", recipientIDs);
                                                          UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Invitation(s) sent successfuly!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                                          [alrt show];
                                                          alrt = nil;
                                                      }





                                                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:FacebookInviteSuccess delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Proceed" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                      alert.tag = 14114;
                                                      [alert show];
                                                      alert = nil;

                                                  }

                                                  else if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogCompleted && [strResultUrl isEqualToString:@"fbconnect://success"])
                                                  {
                                                      MIDLog(@"Cancel Clicked");

                                                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancelled" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Proceed" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                      alert.tag = 14114;
                                                      [alert show];
                                                      alert = nil;

                                                  }

                                                  else {
                                                      MIDLog(@"Web dialog not complete, error: %@", error.description);

                                                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:InternetFailError delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                      alert.tag = 15115;
                                                      [alert show];
                                                      alert = nil;

                                                  }
                                              }
                                          friendCache:self.friendCache]
```

Answer (score 0):

I provided the canvas URL in the application settings under Facebook developer site and It works for me